# How to display results of sqlite database inside my listview in android? can it be possible with arrayadapter ? or cursoradapter?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

i have written a program to display my uid , username and password when clicked on a button as a toast message from my database , but i want to display it inside my listview when clicked on the same button , the listview is on the same page , i am new to sqlite database i just know how to create , insert , delete and update the contents of database, but i dont know how to display it inside my listview , please need some help

Here is the pic of my application
[image]

As you can see from the pic , i m adding username and password with add button and with the help of getdetails button i m displaying my uid , username and password , but i want to display the details inside the listview

My ListHelper class

```
public class ListHelper {

DbListHelper helper;

public ListHelper(Context context) {
    helper = new DbListHelper(context);
}

public long insertData(String name, String password) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DbListHelper.NAME, name);
    values.put(DbListHelper.PASSWORD, password);
    long id = db.insert(DbListHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    return id;
}

public String getAllData() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] columns = { DbListHelper.UID, DbListHelper.NAME,
            DbListHelper.PASSWORD };
    Cursor cursor = db.query(DbListHelper.TABLE_NAME, columns, null, null,
            null, null, null);
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(DbListHelper.UID);
        int cid = cursor.getInt(index);
        int index1 = cursor.getColumnIndex(DbListHelper.NAME);
        String cid1 = cursor.getString(index1);
        int index2 = cursor.getColumnIndex(DbListHelper.PASSWORD);
        String cid2 = cursor.getString(index2);

        buffer.append(cid + " " + cid1 + " " + cid2 + "\n");

    }
    return buffer.toString();
}

class DbListHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "ListTest";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "ListViewTest";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private Context context;
    private static final String UID = "_id";
    private static final String NAME = "Name";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "Password";
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "Create table " + TABLE_NAME
            + " (" + UID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + NAME
            + " VARCHAR(255) ," + PASSWORD + " VARCHAR(50))";
    private static final String DROP_TABLE = "Drop table If Exists "
            + TABLE_NAME;

    public DbListHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
        Message.message(context, "Constructor called");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            Message.message(context, "onCreate called");
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            Message.message(context, "onUpgrage called");
            db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

My MainActivity class

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

ListHelper listHelper;
Button badd, bgetDetails;
ListView l1;
EditText et1, et2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    badd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    l1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    bgetDetails = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    listHelper = new ListHelper(getBaseContext());

    badd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String user = et1.getText().toString();
            String password = et2.getText().toString();

            long id = listHelper.insertData(user, password);
            if (id < 0) {
                Message.message(getBaseContext(), "Unsuccesfull");
            } else {
                Message.message(getBaseContext(), "Succesfull");
            }
        }
    });

    bgetDetails.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String results = listHelper.getAllData();
            Message.message(getBaseContext(), results);

        }
    });

}
```

}

any suggestions are welcomed
please reply
thanking you

Comment: don't use ArrayAdapter/BaseAdapter, use [Simple]CursorAdapter instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use either of them. If you want to have customized listview you can use Baseadapter> Here is a nice tutorial: http://www.pcsalt.com/android/listview-using-baseadapter-android/

If you have a simple listview that doesnt need much appearance attraction and demands performance, you can use CursorAdapter (or even SimpleCursorAdapter). They efficiently manage cursor and improve populating listview from database when there is large number of data (1k-2k items).

Here is a link for simple cursor adapter vs cursor adapter : http://www.gustekdev.com/2013/05/custom-cursoradapter-and-why-not-use.html

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Happy programming.